# Intel Neural Compute Stick 2 gives me error "Failed to find booted device after boot"

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to use the Intel NCS 2 on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

After configuring all the steps, I tried to run one of the examples:

```
/opt/intel/openvino_2021/install_dependencies$ ./demo_security_barrier_camera.sh -d MYRIAD
```

The first time the example worked. When I tried to run it again, I got the message

```
E: [ncAPI] [    150951] [security_barrie] ncDeviceOpen:1017 Failed to find booted device after boot
```

Since then, I could not run the examples anymore. I tried to unplug/replug the device, reboot the computer, etc., but nothing.

I tried to search on internet concerning the error ncDeviceOpen:1017, but I got nothing.
Also, most of the topics I have found refers to Ubuntu imstalled on a virtual machine. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 installed natively on my machine.

The Intel NCS is definitely recognized. In fact, lsusb gives me:

```
...
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 03e7:2485 Intel Movidius MyriadX
...
```

Comment: link to the solution by intel: https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Distribution-of-OpenVINO/Intgel-NCS2-ncDeviceOpen-1017-Failed-to-find-booted-device-after/m-p/1349993#M26266